# SQL Queries and Threading

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

I have to execute several SQL queries and I want to use Threads for this, because this queries have to be executed every 1 second to update or get some different values of the database.

When I try to execute my code, I get the following Error:

> WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe Error: 0 : There is already an open
>   DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

I have read on stackoverflow, that the Connection should **ALWAYS** be opened as late as possible and be closed as fast as possible.

Is there any solution for this Problem?

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Private server As String = Nothing
Private pass As String = Nothing
Private user As String = Nothing
Private port As String = Nothing
Private db As String = Nothing

Dim Thread1 As Thread
Dim Thread2 As Thread

Dim con As New MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

Public Sub New()
    Me.server = "localhost"
    Me.user = "root"
    Me.pass = ""
    Me.port = "3306"
    Me.db = "diagnosedb"
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.ConnectionString = "Server = " & Me.server & ";
                            Port = " & Me.port & ";
                            Database = " & Me.db & ";
                            Uid = " & Me.user & ";
                            Pwd = " & Me.pass & ";"
    Thread1 = New Thread(AddressOf Querie1)
    Thread2 = New Thread(AddressOf Querie2)

    Thread1.Start()
    Thread2.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub Querie1()
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE teileliste
                       SET verschleis = 500
                       WHERE ID = 1;"
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Querie2()
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE teileliste
                       SET verschleis = 0
                       WHERE ID = 20;"
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Connections/Commands/Readers are not thread safe and therefore must not be shared across threads.  Each thread would require its own locals.

Comment: When you start a Thread, you can pass the delegate an Object -> `Thread.Start(MyObject)`. This object can be used to pass parameters to the delegate. Then, create the necessary objects in the thread where they are used. Note1: Trying to show MsgBox from a running thread is a bad idea. The main thread should do that. Note2: Your code calls those threads only once. If you plan to have them work on a timed sequence, you''ll probably face some sort of race condition and/or queued request to the server. The server can handle that. Your code will need a good design.

Comment: Every 1 second will lead you multiple threads open at the same time. Before starting the new thread make sure the last one has finish. Depending on server setting your query can take easy 1-3 seconds and even more depending how far is the data. if it's in the cache then your queries will be fast but when they aren't then you need to expect delays. Also you don't want to freeze the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create and close a new connection within the `Querie1` and `Querie2` methods. You can't have multiple concurrent operations going on with one connection. (Even if you could, you're closing the connection in both methods. One method might try to close it while the other is using it.)

The .NET Framework is good at managing connections. While you're opening and closing them in your code, behind the scenes it's actually keeping connections open for a brief period. This is called thread pooling. When you close a connection, it's actually kept open temporarily. When you open a new connection, it might actually give you the same one.

Most of the time we don't need to pay attention to that. All we do is create a new connection as close as possible to when we're going to open and use it, and then close (dispose) it as soon as possible.